# Python social auth for login with Facebook not working on production server

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, python-social-auth

I am using Python social auth for login with Facebook and Google with Django `1.8`.

It is working fine on `localhost`, but when I deployed it on a production server it is not working. When I click on a login with Facebook or Google button, the browser goes into a waiting state. After some time it gives me a `502 Bad Gateway` error. I'm using `gunicorn` with `nginx` on the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Try configure your Facebook App with the URL of your website

Comment: Yes, Change you website ur (replace website url with localhost in your facebook api dashboard )

Comment: I changed the site URL but the problem still there.
I have also updated the call back uri according to my domain name.